# why can't I access other members from Main() method?

Tags: c#, class, program-entry-point, member

I was told any method can access any other class members within same class by directly calling their names. But this is not true for Main method. You can't access other members unless you instantiate this class. Very inconsistent.

Answer (score 4):

That's not because it's the Main method but because it's a static method. Static methods cannot access non-static ones. That goes for every single static method, not just the Main one. It's because static methods are defined for the class while the non-static methods are defined for an instance of the class (which static methods have no idea about)